# In VS Code, pressing tab advances the caret to the next placeholder instead of accepting the selected quick suggestion. How can I accept it?

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I want my autocomplete to work on first Tab press, but instead it goes to the closing bracket and I need to go back, press <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd> and only then does it work.

I can provide a gif: [tab bug representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjYn8.gif)

Here is a screenshot of my keybindings that contain Tab, they have already been reset to defaults and I have uninstalled an extension called "Tab Out":

[tab shortcuts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OFgb.png)

Also, here is my settings.json:

```json
{
  "editor.linkedEditing": true,
  "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
}
```

Comment: What happens if you hit `escape` just before typing `space-between`?

Comment: @Mark then it works and also it's not like, *highlighted* anymore while typing?

Comment: Do you have the setting `Editor > Suggest: Snippets Prevent Quick Suggestions` disabled?  And what version of vscode are you using as this setting has changed defaults recently.

Comment: @Mark I'm on 1.79.0-insider (because of copilot chat) and I can't seem to find that setting...

Comment: Strange, you are looking for it in the Settings UI?  It has always been there, I don't believe it was ever removed, just the default was changed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, that's just how <kbd>tab</kbd> in snippets works / is supposed to work. Try using the <kbd>enter</kbd> key instead. That should work I think as long as your `editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter` setting is set to `"on"`.

Of course, make sure you have actually selected a suggestion first before pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>. See also the `editor.suggestSelection` and `editor.suggest.selectionMode` settings.

If you insist on wanting to use <kbd>tab</kbd> there might be a better way, but all I can think of is rebinding `jumpToNextSnippetPlaceholder` to something other than <kbd>tab</kbd>.

Comment: It works with enter, but I would like it to work with tab. When I press escape before typing `space-between`, then tab works, presumably because it cancels some sort of other function that highlights the part where I'm typing? I'm guessing it's some other type of suggestion service that allows you to jump to required places with tab, similar how when you would type <img> and it would jump you between href and alt params

Comment: @Stosdenfer yes- you're cancelling the snippet context so the remaining placeholders are left with default values. in snippet contexts with placeholders, tab is used to jump to the next placeholder.

Comment: Can I somehow turn it off or make what I'm trying to achieve by pressing tab be what's done first?